# DataType verification on DataFrame Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I need to validate datatypes of DataFrame.

**Sample DF**

```
val rawData = Seq((1,"First Rec Col 1" , "First Rec Col 2" ), (1,"Second Rec Col 1" , "Second Rec Col 2")).toDF("Raw_PK" ,"Col1", "Col2")

rawData.show
```

**Result :**

[image]

Here is my schema,

```
val types = Seq(("Col1", "string"), ("Col2", "double"))
```

It says **Col1** should be a `String` type and **Col2** should be `double`

**What I have tried ?**

There are couple of ways i tried (traditional way of looping) but want to get rid of that. So here is what i did

```
val df2 = rawData.select(types.map{case (c, t) => col(c).cast(t)} : _*)
df2.show
```

[image]

It is trying to cast **Col2** `String` to `Double` , It showed **null** in **Col2**

**I want to achieve that it should add ANOTHER COLUMN saying its not a valid record to process.**

Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the techniques described here:
https://gist.github.com/dennyglee/c21f59cf81216c1dc9a38525a0e41de1

[DataType verification on DataFrame Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838676/datatype-verification-on-dataframe-scala)

Using pattern matching:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType

assert(testDF.schema(col1).dataType match {
  case IntegerType => true
  case _ => false
})
```